# Skype Calling integration with dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es, skype-bots

I created a test bot with Dialogflow and integrated it with skype as per instructions [here](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/skype) .
The text bot appears to work perfectly fine. But i am not able to call my bot.

The dialogflow bot is Enterprise edition(V2) and it allows voice interactions. The Voice interaction works fine on the Dialogflow web interaction.

The only response i get from skype is "You can't talk to this bot just yet, we are working on it".

Skype requires a calling webhook for the bot, I am unable to find a separate calling webhook from dialogflow for my bot, i have used the default one.